# Spaces after periods in abbreviations

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, periods, spacing

Should I put spaces after periods in the following examples?

- A.B. Buffington (between the initials)
- Vol.2, No.6, pp.195-200

I see people missing spaces in their academic writing all the time and I am not sure if I should correct this.

Comment: By the way, is there an explanation why there is also no space in "e.g." and "i.e."?

Comment: e.g. is short for the phrase "exempli gratia", therefore the abbreviation goes together in one unit of text, and the full-stops indicate where letters have been excised from each word in the abbreviated phrase.

If "e." were a common abbreviation for the single word "exempli" and "g." were a common abbreviation for "gratia" then we would write "e. g.". The space implies that "e." and "g." are separate units, standing for "exempli" and "gratis" by themselves. But that is not the case. "e." all alone does not carry the meaning "exempli".

Comment: You don't _have to_ write _e. g._ without a space.  In LaTeX I use `e.\,g.`,
which gives a thin space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I commiserate with the desire to avoid a cramped, less readable look.

The citation service that I use, Mendeley, gives a choice of four commonly used citation styles. Three have spaces between abbreviated first and middle initials. Otherwise, yes, I think I would add spaces to your remaining examples. So to answer your question, this is what I would do:

> A.B. Buffington

and

> Vol. 2, No. 6, pp. 195-200

Comment: I wonder if there is any rule of grammar, why they don't put a space between abbreviated first and middle initials. Is this really just a matter of taste?

Comment: dima I don't know, I checked the OWL link provided by @Gnawme, but couldn't find any specifics about spacing rationale.

Comment: Hello, Ellie. Your link seems to have evolved somewhat.

Comment: Hello, Dmitry, if you're still around. _Grammar_ and _punctuation_ are seen as being totally distinct (though of course a comma can give a different meaning to a sentence). In other words, here, we're looking for 'rules of punctuation' only. And there are different _styles_ in use, showing that there's no inviolable diktat. (Though your prof or editor may try to impose one, and they _do_ have a say in your future.)  I have found a style guide endorsing the suppression of full stops where clarity isn't compromised (this is quite normal in the UK). So A B Buffington / Vol 2, No 6, pp 195-200.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth sadly, yes. CiteULike was a Springer Verlag initiative that became defunct in 2020, I believe. I will edit accordingly. Thank you for the reminder!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your examples look unnecessarily compact (if not cramped) to me. I would correct them to:

> - A. B. Buffington
> - Vol. 2, pp. 195-200

If you look via this [handy resource](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/949/01/) allowing access to the major citation styles (MLA, APA, and CMS), none of them advocate such a cramped format.

I haven't found a reference for why e.g. and i.e. are conventionally written without spaces. I'll edit my answer if I do...

Answer (score 0):

In Spanish, there’s always a space after a period. For example «a. m. or p. m.» However, I haven’t seen that in English nor found the grammatical rule.

Comment: These (and "i.e." and "e.g.") would look especially ugly if they ended up split across two lines.  To avoid that, I'd suggest using a non-breaking space character there.